# How to receive model via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, groovy

All,

I have two questions one major one minor. My minor question is why does this simple `grails` app not work?

**Person Domain**

```
package ajax

class Person {
    String firstname
    String lastname
    int age


    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
package ajax
class HomeController {

    def index() {
    render (view: "index")
    }
    def greet()
    {
        render "hi"
    }
    def getPersons()
    {
        def persons = Person.getAll()
        render(model: [persons:persons])
    }
}
```

**index.gsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <g:javascript plugin="jquery" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="greeting"></div><br>
<button onclick='<g:remoteFunction action="greet" update="greeting"/>'>Click on me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally my major question is, in index.gsp if I wanted to change the button action to `getPersons`, then how would I get the data via ajax or jquery e.g. `g:remoteFunction`  .And if I did get the data how would I format the data in `#greeting` so I get the `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: could you explain what do you mean when you say "the app doesn't work"? what grails version do you use? In Grails 2.4.x the grails gsp ajax tags are marked as deprecated...

Comment: On the gsp when i click the button it does not respond or do anything. I am using Grails 2.4.2, if it is decrypted what should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following solution should work:

**PersonController**

```
package ajax
class PersonController {
  def index() {
    render Person.list(params) as JSON
  }
}
```

This is your JSON Backend. In the frontend you can use plain old jquery to do a ajax call:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<g:javascript plugin="jquery" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="persons"></div><br>
<button id='fetch-persons'>Fetch Persons</button>
<g:javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fetch-persons').click(function(){
        $.getJSON('/person/index.json', function(data) {
            $('#persons').html(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    });
});
</g:javascript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, you just forgot the converter